# React Draggable - How to remove border?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, drag

I am using `react-draggable` to add drag feature for `Modal`. Right now I am getting a border as outline of a Modal. Sometimes when user clicks outside the Modal then border will get disappears. I don't want any border to display at all.

```
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'

<Draggable>
   <div className={classes.dragWrapper}>
      <Modal>
         <ProfileForm>
           ...
         </ProfileForm>
      </Modal>
   </div>
</Draggable>
```

In style.js,

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dragWrapper: {
    border: 'none',
    cursor: 'move',
  },
})
```

How can I remove the border here?

Comment: what kind of style library do you use along with react ?

Comment: Give a className to draggable and then try to hide border using CSS, if not succeeded then try to look into DOM and find which element contains border then hide its border using CSS

Comment: I am using `material-ui`

Comment: @Sabir its not working, also I found `:focus-visible { outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px; }` in DOM. I tried by making outline as none but its not supporting.

Answer (score 1):

For `<Draggable>` if I add css it will not support.
Instead of adding border try to add outline as none for child `<div>` then it works for me.

```
 dragWrapper: {
   cursor: 'move',
   outline: 'none !important',
 },
```